# Finding and copy numeric value in excel cell

Tags: excel

I have a excel document where there is name of the person in one row and his/her phone in under row. what i want to do is copy the names first from all the rows and paste in a another document and then copy all the phone number from the same document and paste right next to the names columns of the new document.

In my current document: i have this format

```
John Doe
9841482227
Jane Doe
9801022823

what i want to do is:
John Doe   9841482227
Jane Doe   9801022823
```

How can i do this in quickest way possible in excel?

Comment: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/809-excel-copy-every-other-row.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the B cells, apply following formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(LEFT(A3)*1)
```

This will return true for Numbers and False for alphabets as below:.

```
John Doe    FALSE
9841482227  TRUE
Jane Doe    FALSE
9801022823  TRUE
```

Apply a `sort/filter` for B cells and copy all cells with `FALSE` (**Name**) and paste in another sheet (shhet2).
Copy all cells with `TRUE` (**Mobile Numbers**) and place it in sheet2 next to the names.

Sheet 2 would contain following

```
John Doe    9841482227
Jane Doe    9801022823
```

Assuming that all users have only one phone number below them, this would work.